# Going to zero or to infinity? Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, bigdecimal

It is amazing kata at CodeWars.
I started from Double, but after factorial 30! should use BigDecimal. On 200! I improved my code and had a problem with time

Execution Timed Out (16000 ms)

[Kata Description](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55a29405bc7d2efaff00007c/)

[Zero or Infinity description Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM8wA.png)

Please help me to improve my code to calculate more than 200! in quick time.

My code (working to 200! ) Siple tests passed ok, but in random tests with more than 200! I have problem with time. No problem to calculate in my Idea IDE, but server Code Wars can't calculate.

```
fun going(n: Int): Double {
    val factorial = factorial(n)
    val zeroField = zero(factorial)
    val infiniteField = infinite(n)

    val beforeRound = zeroField.multiply(infiniteField)
    return beforeRound.setScale(6, RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble()
}

fun factorial(n: Int): BigDecimal{
    if (n<=1) return BigDecimal.ONE

    return BigDecimal(n).multiply(factorial(n-1))
}

fun infinite(n: Int): BigDecimal {
    var sumFact = BigDecimal(0)
    var factCounter = 1
    repeat(n){
        sumFact += factorial(factCounter)
        factCounter++
    }
    return sumFact
}

fun zero(factorial: BigDecimal): BigDecimal{
    return BigDecimal.ONE.divide(factorial, MathContext.DECIMAL128)
}
```

---

After hint k314159 i try to use hashMap to cash my factorial results. It is working till n< 1000. When n> ~5800  ->  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

I need to calculate really big numbers, like factorial 10_000 !

My code with hashMap

```
val myFactorialHash = mutableMapOf<Int, BigDecimal>(1 to BigDecimal.ONE)


    fun going(n: Int): Double {
        
        println(n)

        val factorial = factorial(n)
        val zeroField = zero(factorial)
        val infiniteField = infinite(n)

        val beforeRound = zeroField.multiply(infiniteField)
        return beforeRound.setScale(6, RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble()
    }

    fun factorial(n: Int): BigDecimal{
        if (n<=1){
            return myFactorialHash[1]!!
        }

        if (myFactorialHash.containsKey(n)){
            return myFactorialHash[n]!!
        } else {
            myFactorialHash[n] = BigDecimal(n).multiply(factorial(n-1))
        }

        return myFactorialHash[n]!!
    }

    fun infinite(n: Int): BigDecimal {
        var sumFact = BigDecimal(0)
        var factCounter = 1
        repeat(n){
            sumFact += factorial(factCounter)
            factCounter++
        }
        return sumFact
    }

    fun zero(factorial: BigDecimal): BigDecimal{
        return BigDecimal.ONE.divide(factorial, MathContext.DECIMAL128)
    }
```

---

a little bit about tailrec for recursion

In practical experiment there is no difference between tailrec or without tailrec

n == 7027 -> everything ok
n == 7028 -> StackOverFlow exception

my experimental code below

```
fun main(){
    println(factorial(7027))
}

tailrec fun factorial(n: Int): BigDecimal{
    if (n<1) return BigDecimal.ONE
    return BigDecimal(n).multiply(factorial(n-1))
}
```

---

Ok, 5 hours later ...
Initialize my hash on max stack capacity

```
val myFactorialHash = mutableMapOf<Int, BigDecimal>(1 to BigDecimal.ONE)

    fun going(n: Int): Double {
        initHash()
        val factorial = factorial(n)
        val zeroField = zero(factorial)
        val infiniteField = infinite(n)

        val beforeRound = zeroField.multiply(infiniteField)
        return beforeRound.setScale(6, RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble()
    }

    fun factorial(n: Int): BigDecimal{
        if (n<=1){
            return myFactorialHash[1]!!
        }

        var counter = n

        if (myFactorialHash.containsKey(n)){
            return myFactorialHash[n]!!
        } else {
            myFactorialHash[n] = BigDecimal(n).multiply(factorial(n-1))
        }

        return myFactorialHash[n]!!
    }

    fun infinite(n: Int): BigDecimal {
        var sumFact = BigDecimal(0)
        var factCounter = 1
        repeat(n){
            sumFact += factorial(factCounter)
            factCounter++
        }
        return sumFact
    }

    fun zero(factorial: BigDecimal): BigDecimal{
        return BigDecimal.ONE.divide(factorial, MathContext.DECIMAL128)
    }

    fun initHash(){
        repeat(7000){
            myFactorialHash[it] = factorial(it)
        }
    }
```

Thank you k314159. I passed this using hash of BigDecimal.
When I found easy way to solve this kata in solutions, my head exploit ))))

I don't understand how it's work, but it is 1 line of code

```
fun going(n: Int): Double = if (n == 0) 0.0 else 1 + going(n - 1) / n
```

Comment: Take the hint given on that page to simplify the expression. After simplifying, you will have less processing to do. Also, if you find yourself calculating n! and then calculating (n+1)!, consider caching the value of n! and using the fact that (n+1)! = (n+1) * n!

Comment: @k314159 You gave me a good Idea, using hash I can calculate 5800! , but If I try to calculate more than 5800! I have Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError     I edited my post, please look at my code if you have a time. Thank you

Comment: Try declaring your factorial function as `tailrec`.

Comment: @k314159 tailrec in my case only decrease possibility to count really big factorials. (((

Comment: @k314159 I should return Double. Not Boolean ((

Comment: Try a non-recursive function, so that it won't result in stack overflow. Set `N` to the biggest possible value of `n` that your application will ever need to use. Then at startup, fill up your cache of factorials. Don't bother with a Map; use the most memory-economic way, i.e. an array. `BigInteger[] factorials = new BigInteger[N];` and then use a `for` loop to fill the array without using recursion. Then, from then on, use this array to do your calculations.

Comment: @k314159   very clever idea with hash initialize before!!! I passed successful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the expression

`(1/n!) * (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!) = 1!/n! + 2!/n! + ... + n!/n!`

Now let's write this expression for `n = k-1` and for `n = k`:

- n = k-1: `1!/(k-1)! + 2!/(k-1)! + ... + (k-1)!/(k-1)!`
- n = k: `1!/k! + 2!/k! + ... + (k-1)!/k! + k!/k!`

You can notice that second expression is one summand longer, and this summand is equal to `1`. All other summands become `k` times smaller because `k! = (k-1)! * k`. Thus, if we now the answer for `n = k-1` all we need to do to calculate the answer for `n = k` is to divide by `k` and add `1`. And we can simply do it in a loop:

```
result = 0
for every k in [1, n]
  result /= k
  result += 1
```

Comment: Additionally, the series converges to 1 (not 0 or infinity) and errors do not accumulate, so `k` can be a `Double` for 6 digit precision.